# How to calculate percentiles given standard deviation, mean and normality

Tags: r, normal-distribution, mean, standard-deviation, quantiles

I apologize if this question is exceedingly simple, but I did not find the answer here on Cross Validated or on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile or on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule.

For example, imagine I have a normal distribution and I know that its mean is 200 and its standard deviation is 10. No problem for its median and its 1-2-3 standard deviations. **How can I calculate the value which corresponds to the 75 percentile? How can I calculate the percentile which corresponds to the value of 75?**

Numbers are provided as an example only.

(I use R)

Comment: To get the 75% quantile, use `qnorm(0.75,200,10)`. To get the percentile for the value of 75, use `pnorm(75,200,10)`. Look at `?qnorm`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me how can I calculate them manually?

Comment: There are no closed form solutions for general quantiles or percentiles of the normal distribution. You can look at tables after transforming your setting to a standard normal distribution with mean 0 and SD 1. Or you can integrate numerically.

Comment: You can find many answers to this question with this search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=calculate+normal+quantile